# Como contar los datos dentro de una Columna e Indicar cual es la columna con menos datos en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Continuando con mis estudios en R me encuentro en generar una función que arroje cual es la columna que contenga menos datos, ya probe con `group_by` `group_by_all` y exceptuando las columnas que no son necesarias y solamente me da error, Alguna idea o solución?
Muchas gracias por sus aportaciones! (:

Tengo un data Frame con 50 Columnas, esas columnas tienen diferentes datos etc, y necesito contabilizar los datos que vienen dentro de esas columnas y poder determinar cual de esas columnas son los que tienen menos datos, Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicho esto, como son mas de 20 columnas y hay columnas que no tienen datos necesito de salida determinar cual de estas Columnas es la que menos tiene datos.

Comment: Hola, podrías dar algún ejemplo de lo que quieres y de tu salida esperada para poder ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: Claro @BastianAndres deja edito la pregunta para su mayor comprension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
colSums(!is.na(df))
```

Gracias a que `is.na()` es una función vectorial simplemente con `colSums()` cuentas por columna la cantidad de observaciones que no son `NA`

Comment: Muchas gracias, y como puedo seleccionar ciertas columnas y que no se sumen todas las columnas, si no algunas.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma rápida de contar los datos es usando is.na(), el cual devuelve TRUE cuando existe un dato faltante, si eso lo combinas con el apply para aplicar esa funcion a cada columna obtienes el numero de datos por columna

```
apply(df, 2, function(x)sum(!is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvio muchisimo, ahora como puedo hacer que ciertas columnas no aparezcan en el conteo. Solamente algunas

Comment: antes de hacer el conteo, hacer una selección de variables, df = df[,c("variable1","variable2")]

Comment: existen muchas formas de seleccionar variables, unas mas cómodas que otras, depende del contexto, si quieres profundizar en eso, te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido mucho gracias por tu ayuda